# Как в selenium python найти div содержащий 2 элемента на одном уровне?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

К примеру, каков будет УНИКАЛЬНЫЙ xpath `div class='z'`,
 содержащий:

- `span data-data-first="bbb"`
- и `span  data-second="qqq"` ?

*Уникальный - потому что у `div class='z'`, Местоположение динамически меняется.

Я могу найти

```
//div[@class='z']//span[@data-first="bbb"]
```

Но как включить в xpath И

```
//span[@data-second="qqq"]
```

```
<div class='z'>

    <div class='z__1'>
        <span data-first="aaa"></span>
    </div>

    <div class='z__2'>
        <span data-second="www"></span> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class='z'>

    <div class='z__1'>
        <span data-first="bbb"></span>
    </div>

    <div class='z__2'>
        <span data-second="qqq"></span> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class='z'>

    <div class='z__1'>
        <span data-first="nnn"></span>
    </div>

    <div class='z__2'>
        <span data-second="rrr"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `//div[@class='z']//span[contains(@data-atr, "atr_")]`

Comment: А если <span data-first="aaa''></span>    <span data-second="bbb''></span> ?

Comment: `//div[@class='z']//span`

Comment: Да, забыл указать что, div с class="z" не один, их 10 штук с одинаковой структурой. Отличаются только значения в атрибутах  data-first, и data-second. Как получить именно этот div, отсеяв другие?

Comment: есть возможность посмотреть на страницу полностью?

Comment: Взгляни пожалуйста на код снова. Я его изменил думаю так понятней. Посреди div Z. У него span data-first="bbb". bbb - не меняется. Статично. Мне нужно узнать какое значение в span data-second="qqq".  Это значение qqq - динамически меняется. И местоположение классов Z так же динамически меняется.

Comment: `//div[@class='z']//span[boolean(@data-second)]` - вот. берем родительский элемент `@class='z'`, `//` - любая вложенность, `span` - все спаны. `[boolean(@data-second)]` - только те, которые содержат аттрибут data-second

Comment: у вас получилось?